# Comparing certificates using Powershell

Tags: powershell, x509certificate

I'm working on a disaster recovery project and I am recommending as part of the plan to do regular audits of the primary and secondary sites.  One of the audit tasks is to make sure that the secondary site has the same certificates installed as the primary site.  I think I can accomplish this using Powershell

```
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My
Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

I know I can use the above commands to get a list of certs but what I'm having trouble with is trying to do this all in one script.  I would like to get the list of certs on one server and then get the list of certs on another server and then compare the two lists.  I'm very new to Powershell so I'm not to sure where to start.

Comment: What have you tried, and what problem did you encounter that you need help with?

Comment: I know I can use the above commands to get a list of certs but what I'm having trouble with is trying to do this all in one script.  I would like to get the list of certs on one server and then get the list of certs on another server and then compare the two lists.  I'm very new to Powershell so I'm not to sure where to start.

Comment: Start [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timid/archive/2009/10/07/powershell-for-non-n00bs-certificates-installed-on-a-remote-host.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To retrieve the certificates you would use the underlying .NET classes since the Certificates provider does not expose remote machine connectivity by default.  You may find another possibility with PS remoting as well.  Here is the function:

```
function Get-Certificates {
    Param(
            $Computer = $env:COMPUTERNAME,
            [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation]$StoreLocation,
            [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName]$StoreName
          ) 

    $Store = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store("\\$computer\$StoreName",$StoreLocation)
    $Store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadOnly")
    $Store.Certificates
}
```

And here is how you would use it to compare two lists:

```
$Left = Get-Certificates -StoreLocation LocalMachine -StoreName Root
$Right = Get-Certificates -StoreLocation LocalMachine -StoreName Root -Computer "REMOTE-PC"

# Dump to console
Compare-Object $Left $Right -property Thumbprint, FriendlyName, Subject, NotAfter | Format-Table

# Export results to file
Compare-Object $Left $Right -property Thumbprint, FriendlyName, Subject, NotAfter | Export-Csv Comparison.csv
```